# Close reason changed: Comparing old with the new

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Recently, the options on the closed vote reasons on StackOverflow have changed.  I was curious about the differences, and would like a bit of clarification on the new one.

> This question was caused by a problem that can't be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Whereas the previous said:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Now, perhaps these are completely different reasons and should not be compared.  But given that one replaced the other, I'm curious if this indicates a shift in how we respond to a question that doesn't include code, but is asking for code.

This first would seem to indicate that the question, while it may include code, might be too specialized to be of value.  Those exist, to be sure, but seem much more rare.  Whereas questions that do not contain code, but ask for it, are prevalent.

If this is the case, what is the best way to respond to the myriad of questions that ask for code, but show no effort?  And is there subtly that I am missing in the new answer that I might look for in other questions?